# What does the notation in this claim, that needs to be proved, mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove, or disprove using a counter example:

Let $p,q\in\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$ \, then $p-q$ is irrational.

I don't understand what the back slash between the $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ means.

Comment: Set subtraction. You're considering the elements in $\mathbb{R}$ that are not in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Normally that means that you subtract a set R \ Q and that would be the set of irrational numbers. So p and q are irrational

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\setminus$ sign means *substraction* of sets.
$$A\setminus B = \{x\in A \mbox{ such that } x\not\in B\}.$$

In your case, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of irrational numbers.

Comment: So, then I just have to prove that subtracting two irrational numbers results in an irrational number?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: Yes, you have to prove that – or disprove by a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

The statement isn't true. Take an arbitrary $p,q \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ such that $p=q$ then $p-q=0 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: if you take any number $p$, then $p-p=0$ and $0$ is rational.